# Python Scrape JSON from webpage

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape the contents of a javascript variable from a webpage.  The webpage is a search page, and when you view its source, it has on the page something similar to

```
<script>var test1='balah';var catalog={};var test2='blah'</script>
```

Where `catalog` is a large nested json structure string.

I know how to parse it, but how can I grab the json string from the webpage, assuming I already have the full page's html content in a single string variable?

Comment: Beautiful Soup (https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is always a good place to start, although it would have been better if your target data was rendered in HTML instead of inside of a `<script>` tag. You might be able to use Beautiful Soup to more easily grab the `<script>` tag, and then perhaps feed those contents into something else.

Comment: Try the link below. It uses beautiful soap, python and selenium to achieve web scrapping https://medium.freecodecamp.org/better-web-scraping-in-python-with-selenium-beautiful-soup-and-pandas-d6390592e251

Answer (score 1):

how about using a regular expression?

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re

content = "<script>var test1='balah';var catalog={'Year':'2019'};var test2='blah'</script>"
p = re.compile(r'[\d\D]+catalog=([\d\D]+?);')
m = p.match(content)
if m:
    result = m.group(1)
    print result
```

the result will be `{'Year':'2019'}`

Comment: One thing to note is that you'll want to ensure that the regex expression only matches the javascript string you're looking for.